# the order of performing asynchronous a few methods in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a three method in JavaScript NodeJS Sequelize.
Calling them is saved as follows:

```
setTransferHistory(senderId, recipientId, amountMoney, transferTitle);
setWidgetStatus(senderId);
setWidgetStatus(recipientId);
```

Each method does update or select in the mysql database.
It is very important that they are made in this order and it is not always so.

I know that solving this problem uses the word then in the setTransferHistory method, thus:

```
  function setTransferHistory(
    senderId,
    recipientId,
    amountMoney,
    transferTitle,
  ) {
    Transaction.create({
      id_sender: senderId,
      id_recipient: recipientId,
      date_time: getTodayDate(),
      amount_money: amountMoney,
      transfer_title: transferTitle,
    }).then(() => {
      setWidgetStatus(senderId);
      setWidgetStatus(recipientId);
    });
  }
```

...but **I don't want** these two methods to be included in this method. I would like to just write it one below the other.

Comment: What's the *problem* with what you have now? You can use await/async syntax, but that's just sugar for the same promises.

Comment: If you want to guarantee ordering, you need to chain the asynchronous calls so that the next one is made only after the previous one resolves. Calling two at once is an error because the second one could well resolve before the first.

Answer (score 0):

Since `Transaction.create` returns a `Promise`, you can have `setTransferHistory` returns that, and defer the execution of `setWidgetStatus` after `setTransferHistory`'s promise is fulfilled. So with:

```
const setTransferHistory = (
  senderId,
  recipientId,
  amountMoney,
  transferTitle
) =>
  Transaction.create({
    id_sender: senderId,
    id_recipient: recipientId,
    date_time: getTodayDate(),
    amount_money: amountMoney,
    transfer_title: transferTitle
  });
```

You can have either:

```
setTransferHistory(/* args ... */).then(() => {
  setWidgetSatus(senderId);
  setWidgetSatus(recipientId);
});
```

Or use `await` - that works with promise, as soon you use it in an `async` function, `setTransferHistory` doesn't need to be async:

```
async function foobar() {
  await setTransferHistory(/* args ... */);

  setWidgetSatus(senderId);
  setWidgetSatus(recipientId);
}
```

Of course at this point you could just use directly `Transation.create`, but it's up to you, if you want to add a layer of abstraction.

Answer (score -1):

All you need to do is `return` the promise from `setTransferHistory` that `create` gives you, so that you can invoke `then` on the result of the call:

```
function setTransferHistory(senderId, recipientId, amountMoney, transferTitle) {
  return Transaction.create({
//^^^^^^
    id_sender: senderId,
    id_recipient: recipientId,
    date_time: getTodayDate(),
    amount_money: amountMoney,
    transfer_title: transferTitle,
  });
}
```

```
setTransferHistory(senderId, recipientId, amountMoney, transferTitle).then(() => {
//                                                                   ^^^^^
  setWidgetStatus(senderId);
  setWidgetStatus(recipientId);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Nowadays when dealing with promises, good practice is using the async/await keywords. They basically allow you to run your asynchronous code in a synchronous manner. Using them, your code would look like this :

```
async function setTransferHistory(senderId, recipientId, amountMoney, transferTitle) {
     return await Transaction.create({
       id_sender: senderId,
       id_recipient: recipientId,
       date_time: getTodayDate(),
       amount_money: amountMoney,
       transfer_title: transferTitle,
     });
}

await setTransferHistory(senderId, recipientId, amountMoney, transferTitle);
setWidgetStatus(senderId);
setWidgetStatus(recipientId);
```

The *await* keyword stops the execution of the function and waits for the result of Transaction.create() and *async* is needed in order to use await inside the function.

Hope this helps.

Comment: While maybe not wrong in this instance, it is *frequently* a bad idea to use `async/await` instead of manipulating Promises directly: you can't make async operations concurrently with `async/await`.

Comment: No you're absolutely right but it's the simplest way I can think of not to have to use `then()` and make the calls to function in the wanted order.

Comment: `return await` is absolutely not a good practice. There's really no need to make `setTransferHistory` an `async` function.

Comment: Could you elaborate ? I know there's no absolute need to make it that way, he could  return `Transaction.create()` as you proposed and use the `then()` function afterwards, but since he clearly states that he does not want "these two methods to be included in this method" I think the use of `async/await` is a good solution.